# Is there a way to transpose the data display in the grid visual in CKAN?

Tags: ckan

I am looking to transpose the data display in the grid on CKAN when exploring or viewing data, is there a way to do that ? or does it need to be developed ?
If it needs to be developed, any guidance please?

Thanks !

```
-------------------------------------
Column1 |  Column2  | DateTimeColumn |
-------------------------------------
1       | SomeData1 | 01/01/2019     |
2       | SomeData2 | 02/01/2019     |
3       | SomeData3 | 03/01/2019     |
etc.    | etc.      | etc.           |
--------------------------------------

Transpose to :
---------------------------------------------
Column1        |       1      |     2      |
---------------------------------------------
Column2        |  SomeData1   |  SomeData2 | 
---------------------------------------------
DateTimeColumn |01/01/2019    |02/01/2019  | etc.
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not as far as I know.  You'd likely want to modify the ReclineView extension or build a new one that further extends it.  https://github.com/ckan/ckan/tree/master/ckanext/reclineview